# Crawling pages to obtain .htm and .txt files from sec.gov

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am pretty much a python newbie and was looking at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53320572/scrapy-to-get-into-next-page-and-download-all-files) on StackOverflow.

Whereas the OP was interested in downloading the `.htm |.txt` files, I was simply interested in using `Beautiful Soup` and `requests` to gather all the links, to those files, into one structure. Ideally, it would have been a single list but I have a list of lists.

The process is:

1. Start with the [landing page](https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?company=&match=&CIK=&filenum=&State=&Country=&SIC=2834&owner=exclude&Find=Find+Companies&action=getcompany) and grab all the links in the leftmost column which has the header `CIK`.

   <sub>**CIK column sample with single link selected on right**</sub>

   [image]

2. Navigate to each of those links and grab the document button links in the `Format` column:

   <sub>**Format column sample with single link selected on right**</sub>

   [image]

3. Navigate to each of those document button links and grab the document links in the `Document Format Files` section, if the file mask is `.htm | .txt`.

   <sub>**Document Format Files sample with single link selected on right**</sub>

   [image]

4. Print the list of links (which is a list of lists)

---

**Other info:**

I use CSS selectors throughout to target the links.

What particularly concerns me, given my limited Python experience, is the fact I have a list of lists rather than a single list, whether my re-use of variable names is confusing and potentially bug prone, and I guess whether what I am doing is particularly pythonic and efficient.

In languages I am more familiar with, I might attempt to create a class and provide the class with methods; which in effect are my current functions.

---

**Set-up info:**

The version of the jupyter notebook server is: 5.5.0

The server is running on this version of Python:

Python 3.6.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Mar 29 2018, 13:32:41) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]

---

**Python code:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from urllib.parse import urljoin

base = 'https://www.sec.gov'
start_urls = ["https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?company=&match=&CIK=&filenum=&State=&Country=&SIC=2834&owner=exclude&Find=Find+Companies&action=getcompany"]

def makeSoup(url):
    res = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, "lxml")
    return soup

def getLinks(pattern):
    links = soup.select(pattern)
    return links

def getFullLink(links):
    outputLinks = []
    for link in links:
        outputLinks.append(urljoin(base, link.get("href")))
    return outputLinks

soup = makeSoup(start_urls[0])
links = getLinks("#seriesDiv [href*='&CIK']")
firstLinks = getFullLink(links)

penultimateLinks = []

for link in firstLinks:
    soup = makeSoup(link)
    links = getLinks('[id=documentsbutton]')
    nextLinks = getFullLink(links)
    penultimateLinks.append(nextLinks)

finalLinks = []

for link in penultimateLinks:
    for nextLink in link:
        soup = makeSoup(nextLink)
        links = getLinks("[summary='Document Format Files'] td:nth-of-type(3) [href$='.htm'],td:nth-of-type(3) [href$='.txt']")
        nextLinks = getFullLink(links)
        finalLinks.append(nextLinks)

print(finalLinks)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you never use `getLinks` without a call to `getFullLink` afterwards, I would merge these two functions. I would also make it a generator:

```
def get_links(soup, pattern):
    for link in soup.select(pattern):
        yield urljoin(base, link.get("href"))
```

Then your main part can become this nested `for` loop:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    pattern1 = "#seriesDiv [href*='&CIK']"
    pattern2 = "[id=documentsbutton]"
    pattern3 = "[summary='Document Format Files'] td:nth-of-type(3) [href$='.htm'],td:nth-of-type(3) [href$='.txt']"

    final_links = []
    for first_link in get_links(make_soup(start_urls[0]), pattern1):
        for second_link in get_links(make_soup(first_link), pattern2):
            final_links.extend(get_links(make_soup(second_link), pattern3))
    print(final_links)
```

I also renamed your functions according to Python's official style-guide, [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and added a [`if __name__ == "__main__":` guard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do).

One way to make this a bit faster (this sounds like it could be a lot of requests) is to use [`requests.Session`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/) to re-use the connection to the server:

```
session = requests.Session()

def make_soup(url):
    res = session.get(url)
    res.raise_for_status()
    return BeautifulSoup(res.content, "lxml")
```

Here I also added a guard so that the program stops if any site does not exists (i.e. returns 404 or similar).

Comment: OMG.... That is sooooooo much better. Thank you for taking the time to review +. I will leave a little longer if you don't mind to see if there is any further feedback.